# Propositional Logic (Find σ)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

We can view the relation |= ϕ → ψ as a kind of ordering. Put ϕ > ψ :=
|= ϕ → ψ and |≠ ψ → ϕ.
(i) For each ϕ,ψ such that ϕ > ψ, find σ with ϕ > σ > ψ.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Pick $\sigma = \phi \lor (\psi \land P)$ where $P$ is some proposition that does not occur in either $\phi$ or $\psi$